# Is a DNS Cache Manager necessary to accurately test the performance of my web application?

Tags: dns, jmeter, profiling, load-balancing, haproxy

**What I'm doing:**

I have several servers that sit behind my load balancer, hosting a dummy website. I am trying to profile the performance of the servers and load balancer with Jmeter.

**What I'm unsure of:**

I was recommended to use the DNS Cache Manager option in my Jmeter configuration. However, is this necessary? Since I'm using a load balancer, doesn't Jmeter only see the LB's IP address?

Answer (score 0):

If your LB has only one IP address - it doesn't really make a lot of sense. If more than one (like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-multivip-overview))- it's highly recommendable (if not mandatory)

Moreover DNS Cache Manager has nice feature of DNS entries override so you can transform IP addresses into human-readable meaningful values like "appserver1", "appserver2", "LB", "DB", etc.

More information: [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps)